# the sql statement used to create a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

what is the query that outputs the sql statement used to create a table?

Comment: Please show some evidence of some research. https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mysql%20create%20table%20example%20stackoverflow

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is on topic for programming questions, but it is a very simple question easily answered by any documentation resource. Please do some homework to answer basic questions like this on your own. Stack Overflow is not a personal service to read the manual for you!

Comment: actually i want to know output that show sql statement that i used at the time of creating the table

Comment: If I understood you correctly then you want to know - How to view the output of execution of any sql statement e.g. a query used to create a table?

Answer (score 0):

You should check it in the output window of the mySQL workbench. It shows the query you executed along with many other useful information like the success or failure result of the query execution, time taken, affected row count etc. I've marked the last query I executed in red box.

[image]

Comment: i want to know select query that will give like CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);
 as output.

Comment: Select query is for selecting records from a table of a database. Why would it emit a SQL statement the way you want unless the query itself is stored in some text column of a database table. What do you want to achieve exactly? Can you please elaborate a bit more?